# How do upvotes work?

Tags: support, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work on Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow)

I know this is a basic question, but I cannot find this in the faq or anywhere else.

How is the total upvotes shown in my profile page calculated? Is it just the sum total of all the upvotes I got on my answer to some questions and the questions I asked?

Comment: Fun reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the total of up-votes you have given. If you've down-voted that'll appear as a separate subtotal.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the number showing how many upvotes *you made*:

[alt text http://img101.imageshack.us/img101/1818/bathog.png](http://img101.imageshack.us/img101/1818/bathog.png)

Comment: It's faster closed than I can draw pictures.

Comment: Keep it, it might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

**### Questions**

**### Answers**

It is the sum of upvotes minus downvotes on the questions and answers, if you are talking about the numbers left of your questions and answers in the questions and the answers sections. The number to the left of the section title is the actual number of questions and answers.

**### Votes**

Not so if you are talking about the votes section, its the sum of the upvotes and the downvotes you casted, with upvotes and downvotes shown separately underneath.